# Finite trees and embedding in infinite regular trees.

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Assume that you have a finite tree $T=(V,E)$, where $V$ and $E$ are the set of vertices and edges of $T$, respectively. Let $d_{max}$ be the maximum degree the some vertice(s) $v\in{V}$. Assume also that you have and infinite $d$-regular tree $T'=(V',E')$  with $d\geq{d_{max}}$.

How can I define a map from $V\rightarrow{V'}$ such that for every $u,v\in{V}$ there exist a vertex $t$ adjacent to $u$ with $d(f(t),f(v))<{d(f(u),f(v))}$?

I know that this map exists by intuition, however I don't know how to describe it mathematically (p.s. I'm from computer sciences).

thanks.

Comment: Your 2nd paragraph appears to be an incomplete sentence. Did you intend to have some equation or inequality regarding the quantity $d(f(t),f(v))$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I fixed the paragraph.

Comment: What if $u$ is a leaf of $T$ with parent $v$ ?

Comment: In this case, the only adjacent vertex that meets the condition is $v$ itself i.e., $v=t$ and $d(f(v),f(v))<d(f(u),f(v))$. Then, I think the mapping must preserve some kind of ordering on vertices from the finite tree $T$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view both $T$ and $T'$ as rooted trees by designating a vertex as the root arbitrarily.  Define $r$ and $r'$ as the respective roots of $T$ and $T'$.  We now work with these rooted viewings, which define an ancestor/descendant relationship between the vertices.  For some $v \in V \cup V'$, choose an ordering of the children of $v$ and denote the $i$-th child of $v$ as $Ch_i(v)$.

You can define $f$ as $f(r) = r'$, and recursively for some $v \in V$, let $f(Ch_i(v)) = Ch_i(f(v))$ for all children of $v$ (noting that $Ch_i(f(v))$ must exist since $f(v)$ has at least as many children as $v$).
Essentially $f$ finds a subtree of $T'$ that is isomorphic to $T$.

Now, for some $u, v \in V$.  If $v$ is an ancestor of $u$ (ie $v$ is on the path from $u$ to $r$ in the rooted view of $T$), take $t$ as the parent of $u$, and $d(f(t), f(v)) < d(f(u), f(v))$ is immediate.

If $v$ is a descendent of $u$, take $t$ as the single child of $u$ on the path from $u$ to $v$ in $T$.  The same argument applies.

So the last case is when $u$ and $v$ are 'unrelated', meaning that none is an ancestor of the other.  This means the $u,v$ path goes through the parent of $u$.  So take $t$ as the parent of $u$, and the rest follows.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. For some pair $u,v$ the 
'mapped distance' $d(f(u),f(v))$ must be minimal.
This implies that you cannot find any $t$, adjacent or not,
with $d(f(t),f(v))<d(f(u),f(v))$.

Comment: I think this is possible. If t lies in the geodesic path that connects $u$ and $v$, then $d(f(t),f(v))<d(f(u),f(v))$, is not it?

Comment: No distance can be smaller than the minimum distance, so if this is not a 'prove or disprove' kind of question, you probably made an error in writing down the problem.